# Jinja2 + google app engine python-2 не работает метод get_template

Tags: python, python-2.x, jinja2, google-app-engine

Код не выполняется из-за вызова метода **get_template** внутри класса **MainHandler**. Если, к примеру, инициализировать **template** как глобальную переменную, то всё работает. В чём причина?
Браузер выдает синтаксическую ошибку

```
import os
import jinja2
import webapp2

jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '\Templates')
)


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = jinja_env.get_template('example.html')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: мб сборщик мусора удалил объект в `template = jinja_env.get_template('example.html')`? во время выполнения get, был создан объект и единственной ссылкой на него была переменная `template`, после того как функция завершилась, переменная была удалена, а с ней и пропали все ссылки на тот объект и он тоже был уничтожен. Я не знаю webapp2, но предположил бы что в get нехватает `return template`. UPD: быстро погуглил c про шаблоны и нашел `self.response.out.write`: http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/gettingstarted/templates.html?highlight=RequestHandler

Comment: Вместе с self.response.out.write тоже не работает. Он ведь только выводит содержимое шаблона. А что выводить, если объект просто не создается внутри класса